# Modifying the 2nd match in a UTF-16 input file

Tags: shell, text, unicode, replace

I'm trying to perform text substitution on a UTF-16 file [steamui_english.txt](http://db.tt/sTSOtL6D)

I wish to replace only the second instance of the line

```
"Steam_Root_Title"  "Steam"
```

with the replacement value

```
"Steam_Root_Title"  ""
```

(note that the columns are tab-separated).

EDIT: This is a bash script, I'm on OS X, not that it will change much...
And I've tried too much solutions to list them here!

Comment: I can probably help you but your question is not clear. First of all, what OS and scripting language are you talking about?

Comment: In the future, by the way -- instead of saying "everything I saw here doesn't work", describe _exactly_ what you tried that failed.

Comment: OS X does change quite a bit, compared to Linux or Cygwin, since GNU tools aren't standard there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sed, but will want to convert to UTF-8 during processing:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 input.txt \
  | sed '0,/"Steam_Root_Title"/! {0,/"Steam_Root_Title"/ s/"Steam"/""/}' \
  | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 \
  >output.txt
```

If you wanted to do this in pure bash, you could try something like the following:

```
count=0
while read; do
  if [[ $REPLY = '"Steam_Root_Title"'* ]] ; then
    (( count++ ))
    if (( count == 2 )) ; then
      printf '"Steam_Root_Title"\t""\n'
    else
      echo "$REPLY"
    fi
  else
    echo "$REPLY"
  fi
done < <(iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 in.txt) | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 >out.txt
```

Comment: I get this error: sed: 1: "0,/"Steam_Root_Title"/! ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: @ItsMeMario Use GNU sed. Or, if you have a recipe someone else gave you using awk or another tool (but which failed when you tried it previously), you can use those too; having the iconv invocations on each side should be sufficient to allow normal UNIX tools to work with your file where they couldn't before.

Comment: @ItsMeMario provided a version which relies only on bash and iconv, removing the GNU sed dependency.

Comment: This answer works perfectly! Single (piped) command, all bash.. very nice! Thank you so much Charles Duffy!